# Effectively handle forms in a React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React functional component in Typescript, where I am using a form(not a real form) but some input fields and a submit button.

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder={t('enter_last_name')} />
<input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder={t('enter_last_name')} />
<input type="text" placeholder={t('enter_email_address')} />
...
<Link to="/nextPage"><Button>Submit</Button></Link>
```

I am currently using a useState way of approach for all the input fields, something like this:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
const onChange = (event) => {
    setFirstName(event.target.value);
}
```

I am not very sure of this approach as I am having many input fields and would like to have all details of input fields stored once I click the Submit button

Comment: Care to expand upon, or clarify, the meaning of "like to have all details of input fields stored once I click the Submit button"? Looks like you have a different `onChange` handler for each input... are you asking if there's a better, or more optimal, way to handle input/field state?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one state to update:

```
const [userInfor, setUserInfor] = useState({firstName: '', lastName: '' });

<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder={t('enter_last_name')} onChange={onChange} />

const onChange = (event) => {
    setUserInfor(preState => ({...preState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}));
}
```

Comment: `[event.target.value]: event.target.value` would create a bunch of new keys on every change. ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried this, but I am getting: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null" after typing one character in inputField

Comment: So why can use `event.target.value`? Please make sure you update correct

Comment: could also consider using a useReducer hook as it becomes easier to dynamically implement state and not need to define all the fields upfront